# Encapsulate common construction in deep inheritance tree with Typescript

Tags: typescript, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, super

I have this working TS code, it's a deep inheritance tree, what I want is to combine configurations (simplified sample):

```
abstract class Basechart {
    config = {};

    constructor() {
        this.addConf({ baseOpt: 'baseOpt' });
    }

    addConf(newConf = {}) {
        this.config = { ...this.config, ...newConf }; // combining configs
    }
}
class Serial extends Basechart {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.addConf({ serialOpt: 'serialOpt' });
    }
}
class Bar extends Serial {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.addConf({ barOpt: 'barOpt' });
    }
}
class Pyramid extends Bar {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.addConf({ pyramidOpt: 'pyramidOpt' });
    }
}

var p = new Pyramid();
alert(JSON.stringify(p.config));
```

As expected it prints a combined config:

`{"baseOpt":"baseOpt","serialOpt":"serialOpt","barOpt":"barOpt","pyramidOpt":"pyramidOpt"}`

What I want is to encapsulate the repeated/common part of my code (constructors), because all subClasses are instantiated the same way (adding specific config), then it should be defined in only one place, it would be something like:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.addConf(this.mySpecificConfig());
}
```

I tried structuring code in different ways but I can't achieve it (get combined conf + DRY).
Is there a way to accomplish it in Typescript?
Does it exist some design pattern in theoretical OOP for this?

EDIT
In the real use case I have a deep json with a lot of nested properties in each config, then something like `config.opt = 'someValue'` is not a good idea (it would be: config.opt.subOpt1.subOpt2.subOpt3 = 'someValue')

some ideal Implementation would be something like:

```
abstract class Basechart {
    config = {};
    myConf = { baseOpt: 'baseOpt' };

    constructor() {
        // this.config = merge(this.myConfig, ...myParentConfig); 
    }
}
class Serial extends Basechart {
    myConf = { serialOpt: 'serialOpt' };
}
class Bar extends Serial {
    myConf = { barOpt: 'barOpt' };
}
class Pyramid extends Bar {
    myConf = { pyramidOpt: 'pyramidOpt' };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an additional answer that does what you require using TypeScript decorators:

```
function Options(opts: Object) { 
  return <T extends { new(...args: any[]): {} }>(clx: T) => {
    return class extends clx {
        constructor(...args: any[]) { 
            super({...args[0], ...opts });
        }
    }
  }
}


abstract class Basechart {
  config = {};
  myConf = { baseOpt: 'baseOpt' };

  constructor(opts:Object) { 
    this.config = {...opts, ...this.myConf}
  }
}

@Options({ serialOpt: 'serialOpt' })
class Serial extends Basechart {
}

@Options({ barOpt: 'barOpt' })
class Bar extends Serial {
}

@Options({ pyramidOpt: 'pyramidOpt' })
class Pyramid extends Bar {
}

var p = new Pyramid();
alert(JSON.stringify(p.config));
```

**Disclaimer**: this answers your question, but I am not saying it is necessarily a good idea :-)

Comment: Thanks @Iwallent, yes this answer my question but is really complex. I will learn Typescript decorators, and Typescript implementation of Decorator pattern (is it the same?). I think there must be a simple approach to inherit common construction

Comment: Typescript decorators are not related to the Decorator pattern. They are like Java annotations or C# attributes if you are familiar with those.

Comment: I suspected that, but I don't know if you can implement decorator pattern in TS with TS annotations (TS decorators)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Decorator Pattern where you decorate the parent. Your code could then be rewritten as:

```
abstract class Basechart {
  public get config():Object { return { baseOpt: 'baseOpt'}}
}
class Serial extends Basechart {
  public get config():Object { return {...super.config, serialOpt: 'serialOpt' } }
}
class Bar extends Serial {
  public get config():Object { return {...super.config, barOpt: 'barOpt' } }
}
class Pyramid extends Bar {
  public get config():Object { return {...super.config, pyramidOpt: 'pyramidOpt' } }
}

var p = new Pyramid();
console.log(JSON.stringify(p.config));
```

Comment: But your design still repeat things: 1) all subclasses has a method that return a merge; 2)merge logic (spread operator). Anyway, your example is cleaner, could you please adapt it to work in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ ? thanks

Comment: Did you see my new answer? That is exactly what you are asking for!, right?